# How to remove duplicate jars from a gwt-application runtime config file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt

I am currently working towards upgrading our client side GWT setup, which we use when we deploy apps to google app engine. We also use DataNucleus's JDO on google app engine. The project is built using maven.

I have the following error below that occurs during runtime for my GWT app runconfig in legacy dev mode (the mode should not matter):

> Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already registered. Ensure you
>   dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath.
>
> The URL
>   ".../target/project/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-core-3.1.3.jar"
>   is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical
>   plugin located at URL
>   ".../.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/3.1.3/datanucleus-core-3.1.3.jar."
>       at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerBundle(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:541)

I understand that this is a duplicate jar and I need to remove the duplicate. I am just at a loss for how to do it easily in my gwt app runtime configuration. What happens is that inside the runtime config, it uses the "default classpath". The default classpath includes the following:

- Eclipse Project Name

  - (bunch of things like /src/main/java etc.)
  - /target/*
- Maven Dependencies

There is the problem though. The datanucleus jar exists in the target/project/web-inf/lib folder and maven dependences. The maven build put the dependencies in the target folder, so the build is doing the right thing and the runtime config just has a duplicate pointer so to speak.

When I try to tweak the runtime config file, I do not have the ability to edit the "default classpath" included under the Classpath tab. It is an un-editable bundle in eclipse. The next thing I could do is remove that default classpath bundle, but then I have to manually add each jar to my runtime config by hand, which may take a couple hours.

Is there some sort of way to craft my own classpath that has everything from the default classpath less a folder or two and be picked up in the "Classpath" tab?

Is there a better way?

Comment: You can also ask GWT questions from GWT developers here: https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt

Comment: Is there a better way? yes. ignore eclipse, use your own server and start the superdevmode from the commandline. compare with gwtboot or a archetype

Comment: Yesterday I discussed this with some knowledgeable people on gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt. It sounds like it may have to do with which runconfig I am using. I started by immediately creating a GWT Development Mode (Devmode) runtime config. I should have started with the approach in this article instead: http://gwt-plugins.github.io/documentation/gwt-eclipse-plugin/servers/AppEngine.html. I still need to try it.